# How to use SSML with Web Speech API

Tags: google-chrome, webspeech-api

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

msg.text = "ssml";
speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

It did not work. The voice attempted to narrate the XML tags.

Is this code valid? Do I have to provide an XMLDocument object instead?

Comment: What environment are you using? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952736/the-right-way-to-use-ssml-with-web-speech-api) is a similar discussion for Chrome.

Comment: I am using chrome environment

Comment: This seems to be a known bug for Chrome. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88072 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428902.