# The question of whether speechSynthesis is allowed to run without user interaction

Tags: javascript, browser, speech-synthesis, browser-feature-detection

It seems that speechSynthesis is not allowed to run without user interaction, on some devices, some of the time. My PC browser used to warn about it, but now it works (I don't know if I managed to accidentally change something about permissions in the meantime), while my Android-powered tablet seems to allow it from `localhost`  on `http`, but disallows it from my production site on `https`. Phones always disallow it.

I'm wondering if there is some method of determining whether it's allowed on the running device, so that I can show a notice, or hide the options that offer text-to-speech in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's browser-dependent. Chrome, at least, used to permit speech by default without user interaction, but that changed [a bit ago](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5687444770914304). One hacky way of checking would be to queue an *empty* utterance, then look to see if either `SpeechSynthesis.speaking` or `SpeechSynthesis.pending` is `true`:

```js
// Allowed:
btn.onclick = () => {
  speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(''));
  const worked = speechSynthesis.speaking || speechSynthesis.pending;
  console.log(worked);
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

```js
// Not allowed, silent failure:
speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(''));
const worked = speechSynthesis.speaking || speechSynthesis.pending;
console.log(worked);
```

Unfortunately, `speechSynthesis.speak` doesn't throw (even asynchronously) when speech is prevented due to no user interaction first, so checking the `speaking` property looks to be the only other way.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The first example with `onclick` event still says `false`. And this is on my PC Firefox, where both of them should ideally say `true` (since no-interaction speaking does work in practice)

Comment: Looks like with Firefox, new utterances turn on the `pending` state instead of the `speaking` state.

Comment: Is listening for `error` event on the utterance not a viable solution?